# How to delete programatic added DIV by button clicked without postback from code behind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

After user has just already uploaded some images into the server then I will show up those images to the user for deleting some unwanted.

After the user has clicked the delete button, the system do delete those images perfectly but it does refresh the page and wiped out the other wanted images from the page(but still exited in the server's folder).

I want the page just do delete the unwanted files and it's DIV only. Please help.

I've tried to wrapped them with the UpdatePanel but it's never worked.

This is my HTML code.

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scmImages" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updImages" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="row py-2 px-2 my-3 mx-0 border border-secondary rounded" id="divImages" runat="server">
    <div class="col pb-2 border-bottom border-secondary text-center" runat="server">
      <asp:Button ID="btDeleteImage" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-danger px-5" OnClick="BtDeleteImage_Click" />
    </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
      <%--Div class 'divImageCol' and it's children will be add from here--%>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btDeleteImage" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is how I show up the uploaded images.
The uploaded images will be show in 'divImages'.

```
    protected void BtUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FuImages.HasFile)
            {
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images/TestFiles/"));
                FileInfo[] serverFiles = dir.GetFiles();
                int highestName = 0;
                if (serverFiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    int countSeverFiles = serverFiles.Length;
                    int i = 0;
                    int[] file = new int[countSeverFiles];
                    foreach (FileInfo fileName in serverFiles)
                    {
                        Int32.TryParse(fileName.Name.Remove(fileName.Name.IndexOf('.')), out file[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                    highestName = file.Max();
                }
                int countUploadingFiles = FuImages.PostedFiles.Count;
                hdfImagesName.Value = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < countUploadingFiles; i++)
                {
                    string savePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/TestFiles/");
                    string newFileName = (highestName + i + 1).ToString() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FuImages.PostedFiles[i].FileName);
                    savePath += newFileName;
                    hdfImagesName.Value += newFileName + "; ";
                    FuImages.PostedFiles[i].SaveAs(savePath);
                    divImages.Controls.Add(AddImages(newFileName, newFileName));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            ModelErrorText.InnerHtml = err.ToString();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
        }
    }

    private HtmlGenericControl AddImages(string ID, string ImageFileName)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl divImageCol = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        HtmlImage dataImage = new HtmlImage();
        HtmlInputCheckBox checkBox = new HtmlInputCheckBox();

        divImageCol.Attributes.Add("class", "col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 px-1 my-1 text-center divImageCol");
        divImageCol.Attributes.Add("id", ID);
        divImageCol.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        dataImage.Attributes.Add("class", "img-fluid img-thumbnail data-image");
        dataImage.Src = "../Images/TestFiles/" + ImageFileName;

        checkBox.Style.Add("display", "none");

        divImageCol.Controls.Add(dataImage);
        divImageCol.Controls.Add(checkBox);

        return divImageCol;
    }
```

This is the code for delete the unwanted images.

```
    protected void BtDeleteImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = Regex.Split(hdfImagesToDelete.Value.ToString(), "; ");
        foreach (string f in files)
        {
            if (File.Exists(savePath + f)) File.Delete(savePath + f);
            divImages.Controls.Remove(divImages.FindControl(f));
        }
    }
```

I want the page just do delete the unwanted files and it's DIV only. Please help.

Comment: ´divImages.Controls.Remove(divImages.FindControl(f));´ is deleting somethign?

Comment: "divImages" is a row, so I want to delete controls name = f inside the "divImages". ("f" is a string variable to store a control's id)

Answer (score 0):

The UpdatePanel is working only with compatible controls. If you want to show/hide elements you have to wrap them in ASP.NET controls.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updImages" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:Panel id="pnlImages" runat = "server">
            <div class="row py-2 px-2 my-3 mx-0 border border-secondary rounded" id="divImages" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        ...
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So show/hide in the code behind, you can access the panel by its id.

```
pnlImages.Visible = true/false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to hide the div instead of "removing" her (like @Sebastian said) with something like:

```
f.Visible = false;
```

If you really want to remove the control, you need to use JavaScript or jQuery...